# Install Bootcamp on external drive where OS X installed

Tags: bootcamp, macos, ssd, external-disk, windows

I have 128G SSD internal storage.  And wanted to install Bootcamp on external drive (USB storage).

Found out that Bootcamp could not be installed on the external drive.  So I thought to install OS X on external drive.  Boot external drive with OS X and then try to install Bootcamp on that external drive.

I made my way up to Bootcamp, while running Bootcamp is says that my drive should be journaled, whereas it exactly is.

Anyone maybe tried this or Bootcamp can be installed strictly on internal Mac storage?  It just I'm seeing external drive should some kind of a internal when OS X is booting from there.

Any thoughts?

Ivan.

Answer (score 1):

http://twocanoes.com/products/mac/winclone

When deploying bootcamp, accommodate ever-evolving OS X capabilities with some research. Bootcamps are always temporary.